# I have an error in autocomplete returning [object Object] value in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

autocomplete returning [object Object] value in angular typescript

I can't understand what is the problem exactly

Html code

```
<mat-form-field style="margin-right: 10px;">
  <input #productName matInput placeholder="Product" [(ngModel)]="objTaxInvoice.ProductName" aria-label="ProductName" [matAutocomplete]="autop" [formControl]="productCtrl">
  <mat-autocomplete #autop="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onProductSelectionChanged($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts | async" [value]="product">
      <span>{{product.Name}}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

component code

```
 getProducts(): void {
    this.productservice.getProductList().subscribe(data => {
      this.products = data;
      this.filteredProducts = this.productCtrl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.Name),
          map(name => name ? this._filterProducts(name) : this.products.slice())
        );
    });
  }


 onProductSelectionChanged(e) {
    this.selectedProduct = e.option.value;
    this.objTaxInvoiceDetails.Product = e.option.value;
    this.objTaxInvoiceDetails.ProductName = e.option.value.Name;
    this.objTaxInvoiceDetails.Unit = e.option.value.Unit;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide code of _filterProducts method

Comment: as above, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Kinjal                                                                                                                      private _filterProducts(value: string): Product[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.products.filter(products => products.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }

Comment: @FaizShaikh
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1hsxuh?file=app/autocomplete-display-example.ts

for this I tried to create same example code like your's for reference and it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add display function as per mat-autocomplete

like this:

```
displayProduct(product) {
    return product ? product.Name : undefined;
  }
```

and in HTML you have to add

```
<mat-autocomplete #autop="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onProductSelectionChanged($event)" [displayWith]="displayProduct">
```

For more reference you can check on 
https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using both `[(ngModel)]` and `[formControl]` both, in a single input field?

It will create confusions in debugging. If you want to go with `[formControl]` then you need to use`[formControlName]`.

I hope it will help.

Comment: sorry bro it doesn't help

Comment: any another ideas

Comment: Put a `debugger` inside your `onProductSelectionChanged` function and check what you are getting in `e`.